# What's the type 2 error in this situation?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have 2 distributions $p_{0}$(as $H_{0}$) and $p_{1}$(as $H_{1}$) as the probabilities of $x$ in $X$.

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 x &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 \\ \hline 
 p_{0} &0.3 &0.2 &0.1 &0.1 &0.1 &0.1 &0.1 \\ \hline 
 p_{1} &0.1 &0.1 &0.1 &0.1 &0.2 &0.1 &0.3 \\ \hline  
\end{array}
$$

$H_{0}$ is rejected when $X = 0$ or $1$.

So my type 1 error probability would be at $0.5$.

Which one is the type 2 error probability? On a simplified success/failure table I'd get something like this:

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|}
\hline
H_{0} &0.5 &0.5 \\ \hline
H_{1} &0.2 &0.8 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

and I'd end up with $0.5 \times 0.2 = 0.1$ as type 2.

But if I stick with the original table and use $1-p_{1}$ as the values, I'd get something like 
$$0.1 \times 0.9 + 0.1 \times 0.9 + 0.1 \times 0.8 + 0.1 \times 0.9 + 0.1 \times 0.7 = 0.42$$

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Type II error is $$\Pr[\text{Fail to reject } H_0 \mid H_1 \text{ true}].$$  In other words, when you should have rejected the null, you didn't.

When $H_1$ is true, you read the probabilities from the $p_1$ row in your table.  The rejection criterion is if $X \in \{0,1\}$.  What is the probability of NOT meeting the rejection criterion when reading the $p_1$ row?

Comment: $0.8$? Does that mean that $p1$ and $p2$ are independent? As in because we're talking about probabilities here, it just happens that they're following the same ratio?

Comment: @student I'm only following what you stated in your question, which is that under $H_0$, $X$ has the probability distribution given by $p_0$, and under $H_1$, it follows $p_1$.  You never multiply these probabilities together in the way you seem to have done.

Comment: For example:  if I give you a hypothesis of the form $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 6, p),$$ with $$H_0 : p = p_0 = 0.8, \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_1 : p = p_1 = 0.3,$$ then you can draw up a table like the one you provided in your question, except the values are different, constructed from $$\Pr[X = x \mid p] = \binom{6}{x} p^x (1-p)^{6-x}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 6\}.$$ If your rejection criterion is $X \le 1$ the Type II error is $$\Pr[X > 1 \mid p = 0.3] = \sum_{x=2}^6 \binom{6}{x} (0.3)^x (0.7)^{6-x}.$$